# Can the Shaliach Tzibbur walk around while praying?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader

For any of the prayers other than the Amidah, are there sources that allow the prayer leader to walk  around (for no special purpose) while praying?

The question is specific to the Shaliach Tzibbur, the walking is for no special purpose, not during the Amidah and not leaving the shul.

Comment: I've never seen it done, but that doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: Read *[At the Amud](http://www.feldheim.com/at-the-amud.html)* by Rabbi Yaakov Gordon

Comment: Why would he be different than anyone else?